# why Foreach ignore year using Carbon in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

i am trying to get the past three months of data coming from API

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::post('http://example.com/authenticate', [
        'Username' => 'ADMIN',
        'Password' => 'ADMIN',
        'Token' => 'FK98DL..',
    ]);
    $token = json_decode($response, true);


    $apiURL = 'http://example.com/api/SalesOrder/';
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $token,
    ];
    $response2 = Http::withHeaders($headers)->get($apiURL);
    $data = $response2->json();
    
    $past_three_months = Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->format('j/n/Y');
    return view('api.auth.orders.index', compact('data','past_three_months'));

}
```

blade:

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
@if ( Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s a', $item['DocDate'] )->format('j/n/Y') >= $past_three_months)
<tr>
<td>{{Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s a',  $item['DocDate'] )->format('j/n/Y')}}
</td>
</tr>
@endif
@endforeach
```

output:

[image]

and the output when i remove the if condition:

[image]

how can i get the past 3 months of the current year and why the date `19/8/2022` isn't showing with the if condition in the first output?

Comment: `json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given`

Comment: $data = json_encode($data);

Comment: It is most likely due to formatting. What if you format after you've done the sql query?